# How to append Character to a String in a MongoDB Document with C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I want to save logs in my Database but they come in Character by Character.

With my async code at the moment I obviously lose some updates:

```
var collection = db.GetCollection<ServerEntity>(ServerCollectionName);
var filter = Builders<ServerEntity>.Filter.Eq(server => server.ID, id);
var server = (await collection.FindAsync(filter)).First();
var update = Builders<ServerEntity>.Update.Set(server => server.Log, server.Log + message);
await collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
```

I've got a Document looking like this:

```
"_id": "8e93561bf28feeb5a01b6aa29a551822a8f2310ef46ddcfb837ae29bfaa9829d",
"Log": "Udat1\nUdt2\npae3\n",
"Config": {}
```

But it should look like this:

```
"_id": "8e93561bf28feeb5a01b6aa29a551822a8f2310ef46ddcfb837ae29bfaa9829d",
"Log": "Update1\Update2\Update3\n",
"Config": {}
```

Is there a way to simply append a character to the Log property.

Or can I at least perform a find and Update in the same operation with mongoDB.

Comment: so you want to replace `Udat1\nUdt2\npae3\n` to `Update1\Update2\Update3\n` ?

Comment: no I want so append one character to this property

Comment: You can try using an Update With Aggregation Pipeline feature and use the `$concat` string operator to append a character to an existing string field.

Comment: It would be better if you can provide the original document, the value to be appended and the result of the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like @prasad_ suggested with aggregated pipelines

```
public async Task AppendLog(string id, string message)
{
    var filter = Builders<ServerEntity>.Filter.Eq(server => server.ID, id);
    var update = Builders<ServerEntity>.Update.Pipeline(UpdateQuery(message));

    await ServerCollection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
}

private BsonDocument[] UpdateQuery(string message)
{
    return new BsonDocument[]
    {
        BsonDocument.Parse(
            @"
            { 
                $set: {
                    Log:
                        { 
                        $concat:[ '$Log', '" + message + @"' ] 
                    }
                }
            }"
    )};
}
```